# Variables sum is not matching on a blending problem

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I´m traying to reproduce this blending [example](https://www.coin-or.org/PuLP/CaseStudies/a_blending_problem.html) but using fewer variables, this part is working just fine:

```
import pulp
from pulp import *

# Creates a list of the Ingredients
Ingredients = ['CHICKEN', 'BEEF', 'MUTTON', 'RICE']

# A dictionary of the costs of each of the Ingredients is created
costs = {'CHICKEN': 15, 
         'BEEF': 12, 
         'MUTTON': 17, 
         'RICE': 12
        }

# A dictionary of the protein percent in each of the Ingredients is created
proteinPercent = {'CHICKEN': 17, 
                  'BEEF': 2, 
                  'MUTTON': 16, 
                  'RICE': 8
                 }

# A dictionary of the fat percent in each of the Ingredients is created
fatPercent = {'CHICKEN': 10, 
              'BEEF': 14, 
              'MUTTON': 13, 
              'RICE': 16, 
              }

# Create the 'prob' variable to contain the problem data
prob = LpProblem("The Whiskas Problem", LpMinimize)

# A dictionary called 'ingredient_vars' is created to contain the referenced Variables
ingredient_vars = LpVariable.dicts("Ingr",Ingredients,0)

# The objective function is added to 'prob' first
prob += lpSum([costs[i]*ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients]), "Total Cost of Ingredients per can"

# The  constraints are added to 'prob'
prob += lpSum([proteinPercent[i] * ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients]) >= 15.5, "ProteinRequirement"
prob += lpSum([fatPercent[i] * ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients]) >= 12.3, "FatRequirement"


prob.writeLP("WhiskasModel.lp")
prob.solve()
# The status of the solution is printed to the screen
print ("Status:", LpStatus[prob.status])

# Each of the variables is printed with it's resolved optimum value
for v in prob.variables():
    print (v.name, "=", v.varValue)

# The optimised objective function value is printed to the screen
print ("Total Cost of Ingredients per can = ", value(prob.objective))
```

It calculates the optimal amount required of each ingredient:

```
Status: Optimal
Ingr_BEEF = 0.0
Ingr_CHICKEN = 0.77916667
Ingr_MUTTON = 0.0
Ingr_RICE = 0.28177083
Total Cost of Ingredients per can =  15.068750009999999
```

But this does not add up to 100%, when I add the contraint for that to the code:

```
prob += lpSum([ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients]) == 100, "PercentagesSum"
```

I get this result:

```
Status: Optimal
Ingr_BEEF = 100.0
Ingr_CHICKEN = 0.0
Ingr_MUTTON = 0.0
Ingr_RICE = 0.0
Total Cost of Ingredients per can =  1200.0
```

Which is wrong since it does not satisfy the other contrains.

*EDIT*

It seems I have interprete this the wrong way, I was thinking like: 
If I want to produce 3 units, the sum of the inputs should be 3.

I think it is this way then:

```
# The constraints are added to 'prob'
prob += lpSum([ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients]) == 3, "PercentagesSum"
prob += lpSum(ingredient_vars["CHICKEN"]) <= 2, "CHICKEN"
prob += lpSum(ingredient_vars["BEEF"]) <= 1, "BEEF"
prob += lpSum(ingredient_vars["MUTTON"]) <= 1, "MUTTON"
prob += lpSum(ingredient_vars["RICE"]) <= 1, "RICE"
```

Where 2,1,1,1 are is the quantity available for each raw material.

Comment: `prob += lpSum([ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients]) == 100` should be `prob += lpSum([ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients]) == 1.0`

Comment: Yes, it was what what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

> Which is wrong since it does not satisfy the other contrains.[sic]

Which constraint is being violated? If you look at how you've defined the constraints you'll find that they are all satisfied.

```
prob += lpSum([proteinPercent[i] * ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients]) >= 15.5, "ProteinRequirement"
```

Which given the solution of 100 units of BEEF means you have 2*100 = 200 units of protein - far in excess of required 15.5.

```
prob += lpSum([fatPercent[i] * ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients]) >= 12.3, "FatRequirement"
```

Which given the solution of 100 units of BEEF means you have 14*100 = 1400 units of protein - far in excess of required 12.3.

The real problem is that I think you've confused the units a bit. When multiplying percentages you'll need to divide through by 100.

Comment: I divided his 2 constraints by 100, kept == 100, "PercentagesSum",  and find this : Status: Optimal
Ingr_BEEF = 0.0
Ingr_CHICKEN = 33.809524
Ingr_MUTTON = 55.714286
Ingr_RICE = 10.47619
Total Cost of Ingredients per can =  1580.000002 Is this ok ?